# What is the correct way to add include paths when calling a batch file from VSCode?

Tags: c++, batch-file, include, visual-studio-code

I'm calling a batch file to call this code

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64   
set compilerflags=/Od /Zi /EHsc
set linkerflags=/OUT:box.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe" %compilerflags% boxdemo.cpp /link %linkerflags%
```

I've tried to set include directories using `/I` but they don't get picked up.

My c_cpp_properties.json file also has the includes set but is also failing.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": ["C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.14393.0/UCRT","C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/WINDOWS KITS/10/INCLUDE/10.0.14393.0/UM","C:/DirectXCode/imgui-master","c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include","C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.10240.0/um"],
            "browse" : {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders" : true,
                "databaseFilename" : ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I get

> fatal error C1034: d3d11.h: no include path set when building

Comment: `/I` should work. Please read the documentation and if you can't figure it out let us see how you try it using the parameter. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx

Comment: I also don't see where any process accesses your `c_cpp_properties.json`.

Comment: I tried this in the batch file `@echo off
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64   
set compilerflags=/Od /Zi /EHsc
set linkerflags=/OUT:box.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe" /I "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\WINDOWS KITS\10\INCLUDE\10.0.14393.0\UCRT","C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\WINDOWS KITS\10\INCLUDE\10.0.14393.0\UM","C:\DirectXCode\imgui-master","c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include" %compilerflags% boxdemo.cpp /link %linkerflags%`

Comment: That's not how `/I` works. Check the link I posted earlier.

Comment: That seems to have worked, thank you Simon!